# Sonar scanner do not honor analysis permission

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have sonar server 5.6. I created a user group with set of users.

There are couple of projects hosted on Sonar. Currently anybody is able to run the scanner & publish the results on my sonar instance. Although I configured sonar analysis to administrators only, still user is able to do the analysis.

Can anybody tell me how to configure sonar analysis permission.

Atul

Comment: How are the permissions set on your already-existing projects?

Comment: please add screens with "Global permissions" and project permissions.